# my s-video out put won't fit to the tv

Tags: screen, thinkpad

I am using lubuntu on my old think pad t30 laptop.

The problem is with s-video out put and I would like to watch movies on my tv.

I can see my desktop on my tv but it's not synchronized in size. I can't see the right and bottom side of the desktop. (you can imagine how this could get you frustrated).

This installation is my second one. I re installed it after my hard disk gone bad. at the first installation there were no problem. i installed xrandr and the gui arandr but that doesn't helped me.

Comment: Can you tell us what type of GPU you are using (AMD/Nvidia/etc)?

Comment: @neon_overload   it's ATI Mobility Radeon 7500 chipset with 16 mb memory